# Issues with accessing localhost from another computer in local network

Tags: apache, wamp

I have a specific problem when accessing localhost from another computer in same network. 
I've done all necessary settings in httpd.conf and allowed my network ip. Also I've done firewall settings. 
The concretely problem is that at one point I can access localhost with ip without any problems from another computer. But at another moment afterwhile I get error site can't be reached. And that goes round and round, sometimes I can access, sometimes cannot. Wamp is online all the time, apache service is running.
Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Comment: What version of WAMP are you using?

Comment: WampServer Version 3.0.0

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get when you cannot connect

Comment: The site can't be reached.
my_ip_address took too long to respond
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score -1):

1-You should click in the icon of wamp in the task barre

2-click put online

3-now you can access to your pages , you should replace localhost with the ip adresse of the server .

Comment: I did all of that at start. Sometimes I can access, but sometimes not.

Comment: I don't know, network connection is consistent all the time.